# open url connection and wait to finish loading of the url java

Tags: java, connection

i have the following code. i want to get the url after finished loading the url. How can i do my connection to wait to finish the loading first?
Thank you in advance

```
URL u = new URL("http://google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&btnI=1&q=" + jTextField1.getText().toString());
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
```

Comment: Check for con.getResponseCode()==200..

Comment: how to use this? could you help. it tried to check it with an if statement . like if (con.getResponseCode()==200) , but i have to make the connection wait to get the response code..could you help more ?

Comment: see this answer for help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/74057

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpURLConnection ex1 = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
ex1.setChunkedStreamingMode(7000); // enable chunked streaming mode before connecting  to server.
```